# Memory assignment in C through pointers

Tags: c

I am learning how to use pointers, so i wrote the below program to assign integer values in the interval [1,100] to some random locations in the memory.

When i read those memory locations, printf displays all the values and then gives me a segmentation fault. This seems an odd behavior, because i was hoping to see either all the values OR a seg fault, but not both at the same time.

Can someone please explain why i got to see both?

Thanks. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char first = 'f';
    char *ptr_first = &first;
    int i=1;
    for(i=1;i<101;i++)
        *(ptr_first+i) = i;
    for(i=1;i<101;i++)
        printf("%d\n", *(ptr_first+i));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not odd at all. You are using your variable `first`, which is on the stack. What you essentially do is happily overwriting the stack (otherwise known from buffer overflows on the stack) and thus probably destroying any return address and so on.

Since `main` is called by the libc, the return to libc would cause the crash.

Comment: So does my results mean that c would let me read and write the stack, but in the end, simply give a warning that i caused a seg fault? This does not seem safe, i was hoping that the program either crashes completely and i see a seg fault OR i get to see my values. But the fact that both happened, it seems like Seg fault is just being issued like a warning, instead of a fatal error.

Comment: In some systems this will crash without execution. For example, Linux with ExecShield active.

Comment: Nice answer. Just to elaborate. The OP's question was why the numbers are printing OK and he's still getting a segfault, as opposed to an immediate segfault on mem-write, or no segfault at all. The stack on many popular architectures (e.g. x86) grows down, i.e. towards lower memory addresses, so `*(ptr+i)` which points to *higher* memory addresses, often don't point to unallocated areas of memory, but rather higher stack locations that the current program is in control of.

Comment: So as explained in the answer, that allows the read and write without a segfault, and later on, if you've overwritten important stack data, libc will throw the segfault. That's part of what C entrusts the programmer with - if it's your stack, treat it carefully. If the OS or some VM was performing housekeeping on every memory access it would slow execution down.

Comment: No, it's totally a fatal error. A segfault always is. You're seeing both because as STATUS said, you overwrote parts of the stack with the return address. So, since you overwrote the stack, you're still perfectly fine, since you haven't started messing around with other people's memory, hence no segfault. But, when you try to return to your now invalid address, it will segfault, since you are most likely not in your allocated memory anymore.

Comment: to test if my program would crash with ExecShield active, i made following changes to my sysctl.conf. kernel.exec-shield = 1 and kernel.randomize_va_space = 1. then i loaded the sysctl with sysctl -p and ran the program again. it did not crash

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing memory past beyond that assigned to `first`. It is just one character, and, through the `ptr_first` pointer, you're accessing 100 positions past this character to unreserved memory. This may lead to segfaults.

You have to ensure the original variable has enough memory reserved for the pointer accesses. For example:

```
char first[100];
```

This will convert first in an array of 100 chars (basically a memory space of 100 bytes that you can access via pointer).

Note also that you're inserting `int` into the char pointer. This will work, but the value of the int will be truncated. You should be using `char` as the type of `i`.

Comment: I would add to this: never (intentionally) try to access a pointer if you don't know exactly what is stored there. In the best case of doing this, you'll crash right away... in the worst case you will cause hard which can be very difficult to track down, and if you just happen to be really lucky, you'll never realize you made this error.

Comment: What case is above? I am able to read and write in the unreserved memory successfully, but i am also getting a warning like notification in the end that a seg fault happened. Isnt Seg fault's behavior defined by any posix standard?

Comment: It's not unreserved memory.  If the stack grows downwards, it's the return address and possibly the frame pointer and then the stack frame of the code that calls `main()` and so on.  If the stack grows upwards, it's whatever padding is needed to align the pointer variable followed by the first byte of the pointer variable itself, then all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

since ptr_first pointer is pointing to a char variable first. Now when you are incrementing ptr_first, so incremented memory address location can be out of process memory address space, thats why kernel is sending segmentation fault to this process.